# Opencv imshow camera is not work second time in a thread

Tags: python, opencv

code:

```
import cv2
from threading import Thread

class viewer:
    def run(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while True:
            rval, frame = self.cap.read()
            cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(20)
            if key == 27: # exit on ESC
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                self.cap.release()
                break
v = viewer()
while True:
    a = input("1 to show, sth to close")
    b = None
    if(a == "1"):
        b = Thread(target=v.run,args=())
        b.start()
    else:
        break
```

Problem is for the first time I enter 1, imshow works. However, after second time I give 1 as input, nothing is showed up.

In main program I had GUI maintained by main thread so I need to handle camera with other threads.So is there a way I can close and reopen camera with opencv in threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. For people who may encountered this type problem in future;
I solved problem with handling only one threads other than multiple threads.
So the code takes below is shows camera on screen whenever you give input as 1. Now you can do whatever you want in main thread.

```
import cv2
from threading import Thread
import time

class viewer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cont = False
    def run(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while True:
            while self.cont:
                rval, self.frame = self.cap.read()
                
                cv2.imshow("window", self.frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(20)
                if key == 27: # exit on ESC
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    self.cont = False
                    break
            time.sleep(0.25)
            
    def openCamera(self):
        self.cont = True
        
        
v = viewer()
a = Thread(target=v.run,args=())
a.start()
while True:
    a = input("1 to open camera")
    if(a == "1"):
        v.openCamera()
    else:
        break
```